# Forgot how to plot restricted cubic spline (RCS) after COX regression

Tags: plot, rms, cox

everyone

A month ago I successfully drew the RCS plot after a COX regression. Unfortunately, I did not save the code and it seems my R has cleared the command history. I only have the picture of the RCS. I remember I used some package to derive the RCS plot, but I cannot identify it.

Here is the RCS plot derived. Thank you.

[HR RCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcNh4.jpg)

I tried to analyze some data. I expect the result shown in the picture I have uploaded. I totally forgot how to do that and I am not able to find command history.

Comment: Hi.  rcs is not a tag for cubic splines - it is a tag for "revision control system".  Can you remove the RCS tag please ?

Comment: Hi, pal. I have modified RCS to RMS. Have a good day.

Comment: Which software do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ben. I use R for Mac.

Comment: I have nearly reproduced the work. I am sure the package I used to draw the restrictive cubic spline for a Cox regression is called smoothHR. Thank you. I need do more research and practice on that package in R.